# Question about the structure of the new control extending the existing style

Tags: wpf, styles

I trying to use the Style to reuse.
I saw the article as follows.

https://charlesk.tistory.com/66

The article shows how to extend the control to use the existing style.

I became curious about how the style structure to be when a new control is created by extending the existing style.

For example, in the article defined the HeaderedContentControl that has "Style_HeaderedContentControl" key as below.

```
<Style x:Key="Style_HeaderedContentControl" TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                <Border Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        BorderThickness="1" 
                        Margin="5">
                    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                                Margin="5">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                                          TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" 
                                          Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And create a new control by extending the above style as below.

```
<HeaderedContentControl Header="재생" Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{DynamicResource Style_HeaderedContentControl}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="시작"/>
        <Button Content="정지"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

Here, I wonder how the HeaderedContentControl structure to be.

The candidates I think are:

```
<Border Background="WhiteSmoke" 
        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Margin="5">
    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                Margin="5">
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                          TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="시작"/>
                <Button Content="정지"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

or

```
<Border Background="WhiteSmoke" 
        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Margin="5">
    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                Margin="5">
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                          TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <ContentPresenter />
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="시작"/>
            <Button Content="정지"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

or

```
<Border Background="WhiteSmoke" 
        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Margin="5">
    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                Margin="5">
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                          TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="시작"/>
        <Button Content="정지"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

How is the right answer? and could you tell me why the structure to be?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this...

```
<HeaderedContentControl Header="재생" Grid.Column="1"
                    Style="{DynamicResource Style_HeaderedContentControl}">
   <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="시작"/>
        <Button Content="정지"/>
   </StackPanel>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

.. you are setting the **content** of the control to be that StackPanel. The style, however, sets the **template**, which dictates the overall look of the control and specifies where the content should go with this line:

```
<ContentPresenter />
```

So what you get in the end is everything in `Style_HeaderedContentControl`, but with that `<ContentPresenter />` replaced with the content that you provided.

A more simple example is what happens when you declare a `ContentControl` with some content, all you see is the content you've provided:

```
<ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="This is the content" Background="CornflowerBlue" />
</ContentControl>
```

Which shows this:

[image]

Now let's declare a template for it, and set it with `Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate"  TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <GroupBox Header="This is the template">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </GroupBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now you've completely changed the whole look of the control, but your content appears where you've specified with `<ContentPresenter />`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation I can understand your example because it's simple. But there is something that I do not understand yet in my example.
I'm to write a new article about it because It's impossible to explain on the comment.
I hope you answer the article.